# How to embed a foreach loop in HTML in PowerShell

Tags: html, powershell

I am trying to create a loop in HTML in PowerShell ISE, like this:

```
{foreach $obj in $objects}
   <h1>$obj.Name<h1>
{/foreach}
```

But it only prints the last one in the list of objects. What do?

Comment: are you sure there are more than one items in `$objects`?

Comment: Is that an html foreach? Cause it definitely isn’t valid powershell foreach

Comment: @DougMaurer Can you point me in the right direction? It is an html foreach, technically, being done in a powershell script

Answer (score 1):

Use an [*expandable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) (interpolating) [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) and embed a [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) statement via `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--):

```powershell
# Sample objects.
$objects = [pscustomobject] @{ name = 'foo1' },
           [pscustomobject] @{ name = 'foo2' }

# Use an expandable (double-quoted) here-string to construct the HTML.
# The embedded $(...) subexpressions are *instantly* expanded.
@"
<html>
$(
  $(
    foreach ($obj in $objects) {
      "  <h1>$($obj.Name)<h1>"
    }
  ) -join "`n"
)
</html>
"@
```

Output:

```html
<html>
  <h1>foo1<h1>
  <h1>foo2<h1>
</html>
```

---

If you want to define the above strings as a *template*, so you can perform expansion (string interpolation) *repeatedly*, *on demand*, use a [*verbatim*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) here-string, and expand on demand - based on the then-current variable values via `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()`:

```powershell
# Use a verbatim (single-quoted) here-string as a *template*:
# Note the @' / @' instead of @" / @"
$template = @'
<html>
$(
  $(
    foreach ($obj in $objects) {
      "  <h1>$($obj.Name)<h1>"
    }
  ) -join "`n"
)
</html>
'@

# Sample objects.
$objects = [pscustomobject] @{ name = 'foo1' },
           [pscustomobject] @{ name = 'foo2' }


# Expand the template now.
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)

'---'

# Define different sample objects.
$objects = [pscustomobject] @{ name = 'bar1' },
           [pscustomobject] @{ name = 'bar2' }

 
# Expand the template again, using the new $objects objects.
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)
```

Output:

```html
<html>
  <h1>foo1<h1>
  <h1>foo2<h1>
</html>
---
<html>
  <h1>bar1<h1>
  <h1>bar2<h1>
</html>
```

Note:

- Given that `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()` is a bit obscure, it would be nice to have a *cmdlet* that provides the same functionality, named, say, `Expand-String` or `Expand-Template`, as proposed in [GitHub issue #11693](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11693).